# MVC @Html.BeginForm Matches incorrect route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, html.beginform

I am trying to present a form to my user where they can enter a start postcode, hit a button and end up on a page offering driving directions to a known postcode.

The route I want to match is defined as:

```
routes.MapRoute("Directions", "Directions/{Name}/{StartPostCode}-to-{DestinationPostCode}", new { controller = "Directions", action = "Index" });
```

I am using the following code to present the form:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Index", "Directions", new { DestinationPostCode = Model.postcode, Name = Model.nameURLized }, FormMethod.Get))
{
    <input type="text" name="StartPostCode" id="StartPostCode" class="inputGreyed" value="Enter Postcode" onclick="ToggleDefaultText(this)"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Get Directions" />
}
```

The problem is that I end up at `/Directions/Index?StartPostCode=abc123`. It is missing the destination postcode and the name key value pairs. This of course means I end up with my request being processed by the wrong route. I have proved this using Phil Haacks route debugger.

I have tested going directly to `/Directions/TheName/ABC123-to-DT83PX` which works as expected. In fact, I tried this using the following code to build a link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Directions Generated", "Index", "Directions", new { StartPostCode = "ABC123", DestinationPostCode = Model.postcode, Name = Model.nameURLized }, new { @class = "button", @title = "More details on " + Model.name })
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do the following:

a) add the default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

b) Pass the values for DestinationPostCode and ListingName in hidden input fields.

c) Use:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Index", "Directions")) { your code }
```